# DLL hijack privileges

Tags: malware, windows, .net, uac

DLL hijacking means that malicious software gets admin rights from default or it means you need to elevate your privileges first?
Because I tried to change a DLL in Windows/System32 folder, but I can't do it even though I ran my software with admin rights.

Comment: I tried to interpret your question. Please let me know if I got it wrong. As for your second question, that's too open-ended, so I removed it.

Comment: @schroeder, no. i mean: dll hijcaking is means only 1) getting admin rights or 2) getting all possible rights, like "TrustedInstaller" if it's possible)?

Comment: @schroeder, In this forum an example with malicious code is not allowed?

Comment: Yes, examples are allowed, but that didn't seem like that's what you asked for

Comment: @schroeder, ok.

Answer (score 1):

DLL hijacking requires an application that is vulnerable and the code in DLL gets the privileges the program calling it has. If the vulnerable program e.g. runs as `SYSTEM` or with administrator privileges (after the UAC prompt), the DLL gets the administrative privileges, but if the DLL is called from a process running as normal user, it has the same privileges the user has.

You are not supposed nor need to be able to change DLLs inside `%SystemRoot%\System32\`. You just need to be able to place your **malicious DLL in a location that gets searched before the legitimate DLL**, abusing the default [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order?redirectedfrom=MSDN) with [DLL Search Order Hijacking](https://attack.mitre.org/techniques/T1574/001/). For example if a desktop application is using a DLL from `System32\`, it may first search for the DLL with that name from its own directory. There are also [other techniques](https://www.wietzebeukema.nl/blog/hijacking-dlls-in-windows) like *phantom DLL hijacking*, *DLL redirection*, *relative path DLL hijacking*, but essentially the goal is always to **trick a trusted application into loading an arbitrary DLL**.

The *DLL replacement* you suggest is also listed on the same [article](https://www.wietzebeukema.nl/blog/hijacking-dlls-in-windows) from *Wietze Beukema*, but if replacing the DLL requires administrative privileges you don't yet have, that's not really privilege escalation, is it?

Of course there are some limitations. The program might check that the DLL is properly signed with a valid signature. The program might also crash, if the DLL doesn't fulfil its needs e.g. if there isn't a function it tries to call or it returns unexpected data. For these reasons all applications aren't vulnerable to DLL hijacking at all, and DLL hijacking might require the malicious DLL to more or less mimic the behaviour of the original legitimate DLL.

Comment: yes, you are right. when my soft reach victim computer, we need to get admin rights from default user rights.About limitations: what about DLL proxying in that article in you message? is it better way to get privileges?

Comment: If it were always generally possible, without finding a vulnerability, the whole rights management would be pointless. Sorry, I won't help you getting into the system of your victim.

Comment: i said about victims only for example))) sory for my bad english)

Comment: Those are just techniques that exploits certain vulnerabilities. None of them is generally better than the others, as it depends entirely on the circumstances. You have to find a vulnerable dependency, first. Knowing these methods simply give you some advice on where to look. Also, [Dependency Walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/) might be useful.

Comment: thank  for useful links. one more question: it's big difference betwen "SYSTEM" rights and "Admin"?

Comment: If you get either it's pretty much game over for the victim. :)

Comment: need more detail

Comment: You can find more details in Microsoft Docs for Windows Identity and access protection, [Local Accounts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/local-accounts).